Proof of Rogers–Ramanujan identities: interchanging limit and summation
In the proof of the Ramanujan–Rogers identities (§8.4) in Integer Partitions by Andrews & Eriksson, they define a sequence
$$\sigma_n(q) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^j q^{j(5j+1)/2} \left[{2n}\atop{n+2j}\right]$$
and then argue that since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[{2n}\atop{n+2j}\right] = ({\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-q^m)})^{-1}$ we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma_n(q) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^j q^{j(5j+1)/2} \frac{1}{\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-q^m)}$$
Now, as I see it, this requires the infinite sum in the definition of $\sigma_n(q)$ to converge uniformly for all $n$. I tried to establish this with the Weierstraß M test, but was unable to bound the summand independently of $n$. I'm actually getting the feeling this isn't uniformly convergent.
So, how does one justify that step?
EDIT: I should add that the notation $\left[{n \atop k}\right]$ denotes the $q$-binomial coefficients (with $q$ as an implicit parameter):
$$\left[n\atop k\right] = \frac{(1-q^n)(1-q^{n-1})\cdots (1-q^{n-m+1})}{(1-q^m)(1-q^{m-1})\cdots (1-q)} = \frac{(q;q)_n}{(q;q)_k\,(q;q)_{n-k}}$$
(where $(a;q)_n$ is the $q$-Pochhammer symbol)

Using formal power series here simplifies convergence questions like this.

That's a good hint, thanks! Maybe that would have saved me some work. But I figured it out anyhow.

With some help from George Andrews himself, I figured it out. He pointed out to me that $\left[{n}\atop{k}\right]$ is in fact bounded uniformly for all $n$ and $k$ (with the bound depending only on $q$).
The bound that I ended up using eventually is:
$$\left\Vert \left[{n}\atop{k}\right]\right\Vert  \leq \frac{(-\Vert q\Vert ;\Vert q\Vert )_\infty}{(\Vert q\Vert ;\Vert q\Vert )_\infty}$$
This follows easily from the facts that
$$\left[{n\atop k}\right] = \frac{(q^{n-k+1};q)_k}{(q;q)_k}$$
and, if $\Vert a\Vert <1$ and $\Vert q\Vert <1$:
$$(\Vert a\Vert ;\Vert q\Vert )_\infty\leq(\Vert a\Vert ;\Vert q\Vert )_k\leq\Vert (a;q)_k\Vert  \leq (-\Vert a\Vert ;\Vert q\Vert )_k \leq (-\Vert a\Vert ;\Vert q\Vert )_\infty$$
